# Why i get this error from android github?

Tags: android

I use this tutorial :
[GitHub Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/ikimuhendis/LDrawer)

but when i import the this class:

```
import com.ikimuhendis.ldrawer.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import com.ikimuhendis.ldrawer.DrawerArrowDrawable;
```

i get this error:
Can not resolve Symbol ActionBarDrawerToggle.
What happen?TNX

Comment: What did you import?  It would appear that you need to import the sample and make it depend on the library.

Comment: Most likely, you're missing the `'com.ikimuhendis:ldrawer:0.1'` dependency. What does your `build.gradle` look like? Or, if you're using Eclipse, what are the contents of your `libs` folder?

Comment: i import the com.ikimuhendis:ldrawer:0.1 into dependency